# Spring BlazeDS flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint

Tags: apache-flex, spring, blazeds

I have been struggling with this today for quite a while, removing everything but the default channels just to get it going. I have resolved all of my library issues (I hope) and now am getting the error below. I have also included my config files in case anyone can take a look at this. Thanks!!!

```
03:19:51,945 INFO  [STDOUT] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
    with name '_messageBrokerDefaultHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name '_messageBroker': Invocation of init method failed; 
    nested exception is flex.messaging.MessageException: An unknown exception occurred
    while creating an instance of type 'flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

My config files are here:

## messaging-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service id="message-service" 
class="flex.messaging.services.MessageService">

<adapters>
    <adapter-definition id="actionscript" class="flex.messaging.services.messaging.adapters.ActionScriptAdapter" default="true" />
    <!-- <adapter-definition id="jms" class="flex.messaging.services.messaging.adapters.JMSAdapter"/> -->
</adapters>

<default-channels>
    <channel ref="my-amf"/>
</default-channels>
</service>
```

## proxy-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service id="proxy-service" 
class="flex.messaging.services.HTTPProxyService"
messageTypes="flex.messaging.messages.HTTPMessage,flex.messaging.messages.SOAPMessage">

<properties>
    <connection-manager>
        <max-total-connections>100</max-total-connections>
        <default-max-connections-per-host>2</default-max-connections-per-host>
    </connection-manager>
    <allow-lax-ssl>true</allow-lax-ssl>
</properties>

<adapters>
    <adapter-definition id="http-proxy" class="flex.messaging.services.http.HTTPProxyAdapter" default="true"/>
    <adapter-definition id="soap-proxy" class="flex.messaging.services.http.SOAPProxyAdapter"/>
</adapters>

<default-channels>
    <channel ref="my-amf"/>
    <!-- <channel ref="java-amf"/> -->
</default-channels>

</service>
```

## remoting-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service id="remoting-service" 
class="flex.messaging.services.RemotingService">

<adapters>
            <adapter-definition id="java-object" class="flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter"/>
</adapters>

<default-channels>
    <channel ref="my-amf"/>
</default-channels>

</service>
```

## services-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<services-config>

<services>
    <service-include file-path="spring-remoting-config.xml" />
    <service-include file-path="spring-proxy-config.xml" />
    <service-include file-path="spring-messaging-config.xml" />        
</services>

<security>
    <login-command class="flex.messaging.security.TomcatLoginCommand" server="Tomcat"/>

</security>

<channels>

    <!-- Java -->
    <channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
        <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
    </channel-definition>

</channels>

<logging>
    <target class="flex.messaging.log.ConsoleTarget" level="Error">
        <properties>
            <prefix>[BlazeDS] </prefix>
            <includeDate>false</includeDate>
            <includeTime>false</includeTime>
            <includeLevel>false</includeLevel>
            <includeCategory>false</includeCategory>
        </properties>
        <filters>
            <pattern>Endpoint.*</pattern>
            <pattern>Service.*</pattern>
            <pattern>Configuration</pattern>
        </filters>
    </target>
</logging>

<system>
    <redeploy>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <!-- 
        <watch-interval>20</watch-interval>
        <watch-file>{context.root}/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml</watch-file>
        <watch-file>{context.root}/WEB-INF/flex/proxy-config.xml</watch-file>
        <watch-file>{context.root}/WEB-INF/flex/remoting-config.xml</watch-file>
        <watch-file>{context.root}/WEB-INF/flex/messaging-config.xml</watch-file>
        <watch-file>{context.root}/WEB-INF/flex/data-management-config.xml</watch-file>
        <touch-file>{context.root}/WEB-INF/web.xml</touch-file>
         -->
    </redeploy>
</system>

</services-config>
```

Comment: What versions of BlazeDS and Spring-Flex are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a...

```
<flex:message-broker />
```

...entry in any of your `spring-context-configuration.xml` files? I had a similar error, if not the same, until i added it...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have xalan.jar in your WEB-INF/lib folder..issue is related to a missing jar file..